# Cloth object (flag) starts to dissolve during render

Tags: rendering, animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I have a flag like this:

[image: flag normal]

But after rendering the animation, it starts to dissolve and moves weirdly around, and ends up looking like this:[image]

I suspected RAM issues during render, however, I didn't have any other applications open and was only rendering the animation overnight.
What is the reason for this?
It is a cloth object:

[image]

Self Collisions enabled

Subdivision Surface under Modifier enabled:

[image]

Comment: did u bake before rendering? you should always bake before rendering, because Blender itself decides when it wants to recalculate its simulation data

Comment: @Chris No, I didn't. I think that was probably the cause. I'll render it again - thank you!